# How to add data using loop in list in Flutter

Tags: list, loops, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I have a 2-d list, I am adding data using `

```
quotationList.add( [productName.text, double.parse(productPrice.text), _n] );`
```

output is:

```
[[qwe, 555.0, 1], [qwe 1, 5555.0, 2]]
```

now i want to add this 2-d list into my products list, i can't figure out how to do that?
my products list looks like this, with static data

```
final products = <Product>[
    Product('1', "random text", 3.99, 2),
    Product('2', "random text", 15, 2),
    Product('3', "random text", 6.95, 3),
    Product('4', "random text", 49.99, 4),
  ];
```

i want to make make it dynamic using some loops or something, like this

```
final products = <Product>[
    for(int i=0; i<quotationList.length; i++)
    {
      Product(i.toString(), quotationList[i][0], quotationList[i][1], quotationList[i][2]),
    }
];
```

but i got this error

```
The element type 'Set<Product>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Product'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a full working code:

```
void main() {
  List quotationList = List();
  quotationList.add(["name1", 10.0, 100]);
  quotationList.add(["name2", 10.0, 100]);
  quotationList.add(["name3", 10.0, 100]);
  quotationList.add(["name4", 10.0, 100]);

  List products = quotationList
      .asMap()
      .map((index, quotation) => MapEntry(
          index,
          Product(
            index,
            quotation[0].toString(),
            quotation[1],
            quotation[2],
          )))
      .values
      .toList();

  for (Product p in products) print(p.name);
}

class Product {
  final int index;
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final int n;

  Product(this.index, this.name, this.price, this.n);
}
```

Hope it helps!

The conversion from List to Map is needed (asMap) because you need an index as well. If you do not need an index you can use the map method directly on the list.

Comment: can explain this code? what asMap and map functions are doing?

Comment: Hello @ImAZ there are some useful and compact function to manipulate list and maps. Map method is enumerating all list values allowing to make something with it. In this case because you need an index, is needed to transform the list into a map: from ["a","b","c"] to [0: "a",1: "b", 2:"c"]; when you are done you have to translate it into a List again; you can see here https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2 for example or on Dart reference: https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/map.html

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the `{}` braces for the `for` loop inside the list.

Change it to:

```
final products = <Product>[
      for (int i = 0; i < quotationList.length; i++)
        Product(
          i.toString(),
          quotationList[i][0],
          quotationList[i][1],
          quotationList[i][2],
        ),
    ];
```

The loops inside lists and maps don't have `{}`, because there aren't multiline.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```dart
final products = [
    for(int i=0; i<quotationList.length; i++)
    {
      Product(i.toString(), quotationList[i][0], quotationList[i][1], quotationList[i][2]),
    }
];
```